# Eclipse won't recognize my Nexus 5 anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, nexus-5

I'm working on eclipse in ubuntu, I test my mobile app in my nexus 5... Everything was working fine (USB debugging mode is enabled), until tonight : I see that eclipse won't recognize my android anymore it shows me : "**Unknown device ????????**", I have changed the `target SDK` to `19` since  i have android Kitkat 4.4.2, nothing works, then `17` etc...

I have tested the app on another android phone with Android 4.2.1 and it was recognized well.

I find this very strange since I was running the app on my Nexus 5 yesterday and it was working well..

Do you please have any idea about this ? Thank you.

Comment: First off, have you tried rebooting both the phone and the computer?

Comment: "In some cases, you might need to terminate the adb server process and then restart it." Restart adb service. Try "adb kill-server; adb start-server" http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: @EricWoodruff thank you, this was the reason... Do you know where is that from ?
(@MattGibson  : Yes, I had rebooted both of them)

Comment: Have you tried Enabling debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, you might need to terminate the adb server process and then restart it." Restart adb service. Try "adb kill-server; adb start-server"

See developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue :)